# Is it possible to add a capacity to specific form fields?

Tags: forms, capacity

I'm working on a conference registration form that has check boxes for which events the user would like to attend, but some of those events have capacities. Client wants those options to turn off when they reach maximum capacity. I don't think this is possible without some serious work outside of project scope but I don't want to shoot them down without knowing for sure. I am a novice programmer but experienced designer/coder, if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Allison welcome to SO :)

You are indeed correct that this functionality is going to require some work outside of your project scope if you are normally into designing web sites that don't generally have much server-side functionality.

This is going to need a database and some server-side logic implemented in Ruby, PHP, Asp.Net, Java or whatever and isn't in the realms of `just a webform` as you have correctly guessed.

I did consider posting this as a comment, but I think it sounds to me that you're not keen on getting into database hackery etc at the moment; equally if I'm wrong then I'm sure you'll get more help from the community if you have some information about what server-side environment the site will be running in (is it PHP, Ruby, .Net, Java, or perhaps old-skool CGI?).